# Centos 7 RPM Packaging - Create a desktop shortcut during installation

Tags: linux, centos, .desktop, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am developing a cross-platform UI with .Net Core and am packaging it using RPM Package Manager. I have created the RPM file to be locally installed. The %install section of my spec file looks like this

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/%{name}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_datadir}/applications
install -m 0755 %{name} %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/%{name}
install -m 0755 *.dll %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/%{name}
install -m 0755 *.json %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/%{name}
install -m 0755 *.so %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/%{name}
install -m 0755 %{name}.png %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/%{name}

cat > %{buildroot}/%{_datadir}/applications/%{name}.desktop <<'EOF'
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Hello_World
Exec=%{_bindir}/%{name}/%{name}
Icon=%{_bindir}/%{name}/%{name}.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
EOF
```

The project contains the executable for Linux, dependency files, and a .png for the icon. Under the installation step I have created a .desktop file and placed it in /usr/share/applications so the executable appears in applications when the package is installed.

I would like to know how to have the application have a desktop shortcut created when the package is installed so the user doesn't have to make it themselves. I know to do this manually after install you have to access the /usr/share/applications folder using Nautilus and copy the application to the desktop, but I would like for this to be done automatically.

I've tried using a copy command under the post installation section, but I don't know how to copy it to any users desktop who installs the package. Is there a command I can add to my spec file or created .desktop file to accomplish this?

Comment: Several points you need to consider and research: #1- WHICH desktop environment? IIRC, CentOS offers Gnome3 and KDE-Plasma by default, possibly MATE and others as well. You should research how to achieve this on each GDE, then include code in your RPM package that addresses each.

Comment: Packages are never supposed to touch users’ home directories.

Comment: How would this even work?  How would users created after the package was installed get the symlink?  You’d be better of packaging an application that created it on login for graphical users, such as in /etc/xdg/autostart/.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create link post successful installation instead of during, create link in `%post` section for rpm build.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s04s05.html

Something link below

`ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME`